# Checkboxes all showing the same text after switching orientations

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

**Edit: See the accepted answer.  Lesson: Sometimes views will save and restore their state automatically.  This happens AFTER onCreate.  This can cause the overwriting of stuff you did in onCreate.  If you don't have unique ids, all views of a certain kind (in my case textboxes) can be overwritten with the same saved state.** (ps: thanks for your help everyone!)

So, I have a simple linear layout and I want to add some views that have checkboxes with images.  Everything works fine until I switch the orientation of my android phone.  When I do it goes back through the onCreate but this time the checkboxes all end up with the same text.  Weirdly, the images appear fine.

My question is: why is it doing this and how can I make it appear like the first time everytime?

In case that makes no sense here's an example: (Edit: It turns out it always shows the last element's text)

What I see at first

```
[] a *a's image*
[] b *b's image*
[] c *c's image*
[] d *d's image*
```

Then, after rotating my phone, it redraws

```
[] d *a's image*
[] d *b's image*
[] d *c's image*
[] d *d's image*
```

My original code is pretty complex, but i constructed the following that demonstrates the problem.

Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

ArrayList<AnswerView> answers = new ArrayList<AnswerView>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionText);
    title.setText("This is a test");
    HashMap<String, Drawable> answerInfo = new HashMap<String, Drawable>();
    Resources res = getResources();
    answerInfo.put("a", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.flower_orange));
    answerInfo.put("b", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.flower_white));
    answerInfo.put("c", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.leaf));
    answerInfo.put("d", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.flower_yellow));
    setBoxes(answerInfo);
}

private void setBoxes(HashMap<String, Drawable> answerInfo) {
    LinearLayout answerList = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.answerlist);
    AnswerView cb = null;

    //Remove all existing answer views
    answerList.removeAllViews();
    answers.clear();

    //For each possible answer create a answer views
    for (String s : answerInfo.keySet()) {
        cb = new AnswerView(this, s, answerInfo.get(s));
        answers.add(cb);
        String text = cb.getText();
        answerList.addView(cb);
    }
}
}
```

AnswerView.java

```
 public class AnswerView extends RelativeLayout  {

private CheckBox m_checkbox;
private ImageView m_image;
//private Context m_context;

public AnswerView(Context context, String answer, Drawable d) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_checkbox, this, true);
    m_checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.image_checkbox_cb);
    m_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_checkbox_img);
    //m_context = context;
    m_checkbox.setText(answer);
    m_image.setImageDrawable(d);
    m_image.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    m_checkbox.setChecked(checked);
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return m_checkbox.isChecked();
}

public String getText() {
    return m_checkbox.getText().toString();
}

}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:padding="5dip">

  <TextView android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/questionText"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/answerlist"/>
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <Button  
    android:layout_width="200dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Enter"
    android:id="@+id/buttonAnswerEnter"/>
    />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

image_checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <CheckBox
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/image_checkbox_cb"></CheckBox>
  <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/image_checkbox_img"
  android:layout_width="100dip" 
  android:layout_height="100dip" 
  android:visibility="gone"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do you handle config (orientation) changes? Do you have `android:configChanges` on this activity in manifest?

Comment: I haven't messed with android:configChanges in the manifest, so I guess its just at its default.  I actually have no idea what it does... googling now.

Comment: android:configChanges sounds dangerous :)  None of that stuff in my app.  I'm just so confused because it works fine when it first creates the activity, I don't understand why it would be different when it recreates it after the orientation change.

Comment: I looked at you code but couldn't find anything. You'll have to do some debugging.

Comment: Yeah, I have been.  The only think I found is that I am setting the text correctly, and it is coming out (programmaticly) correctly on the "String text = cb.getText();" line.  I don't know what else to test.

Comment: Okay, one more clue.  It always shows the last element's text in all the checkbox texts.  This seems significant, but since I know the imageview is being set correctly, I can't find where I've done anything different with the checkbox.  There must be something fundamental here I don't understand.

Comment: Try the Hierarchy Viewer: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does setting a unique ID for each AnswerView solve your issue? You could achieve that as follows:

```
private void setBoxes(HashMap<String, Drawable> answerInfo) {
    LinearLayout answerList = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.answerlist);
    AnswerView cb = null;

    //Remove all existing answer views
    answerList.removeAllViews();
    answers.clear();

    //For each possible answer create a answer views
    // BEGIN modified code
    int counter = 0;
    // END modified code
    for (String s : answerInfo.keySet()) {
        cb = new AnswerView(this, s, answerInfo.get(s));
        // BEGIN modified code
        cb.setId(counter);
        counter++;
        // END modified code
        answers.add(cb);
        String text = cb.getText();
        answerList.addView(cb);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this is interesting.  Setting the id of the AnswerView did not solve the problem.  But, setting the id of the CheckBox in the AnswerView did.  Of course this only leaves me more bewildered as to the actual cause, but it is a workaround.

Comment: Checkboxes automatically save their state based on their ID. They also automatically restore it - and this occurs after `onCreate`. Your checkboxes all had the value of the last checkbox because each checkbox had the same ID -- so they were overwriting each others settings so only the last setting was actually saved (because it wasn't overwritten).

Comment: So it is not a work-around - IDs are supposed to be unique within their hierarchy. Having non-unique IDs is what causes the problem.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  It was throwing me off because it happens after onCreate- therefore overwriting my stuff.  I believe in this case a ListView with adapter is a nicer way to populate the AnswerViews so I'm switching to that.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Implement

```
onSaveInstanceState ()
onRestoreInstanceState ()
```

in your custom layout AnswerView.

Answer (score 0):

Try as I might, I'm unable to come up with reasoning for why this is occurring (and I would happily upvote anyone who can explain it), but here is a solution.  For some reason, Android isn't happy with you adjusting the XML inflated layout so close to its actual inflation in `setContentView()`.  The solution is to do the dynamic portion of the layout process either in `onPostCreate()` or `onResume()`, depending on your Activity needs.

I would recommend `onResume()` if you can afford it, since `onPostCreate()` is not typically suggested for override...however `onResume()` may be called to often and may mess up your layout.  Here is your example modified to use `onPostCreate()` instead.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    ArrayList<AnswerView> answers = new ArrayList<AnswerView>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionText);
        title.setText("This is a test");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        HashMap<String, Drawable> answerInfo = new HashMap<String, Drawable>();
        Resources res = getResources();
        answerInfo.put("a", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.flower_orange));
        answerInfo.put("b", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.flower_white));
        answerInfo.put("c", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.leaf));
        answerInfo.put("d", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.flower_yellow));
        setBoxes(answerInfo);
    }

    private void setBoxes(HashMap<String, Drawable> answerInfo) {
        LinearLayout answerList = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.answerlist);
        AnswerView cb = null;

        //Remove all existing answer views
        answerList.removeAllViews();
        answers.clear();

        //For each possible answer create a answer views
        for (String s : answerInfo.keySet()) {
            cb = new AnswerView(this, s, answerInfo.get(s));
            answers.add(cb);
            String text = cb.getText();
            answerList.addView(cb);
        }
    }
}
```

Two other things I noticed which may not affect you, but I figured I'd mention:

1. If you want your items to always return in the same order, `HashMap.keySet()` is a bad choice.  This method returns these values in different orders on different implementations.  I would recommend a `LinkedHashMap` or a `List` if you need the order to always be the same.
2. At least in this example, it doesn't make sense to clear your collections before setting them again...since this is only done when the Activity is reconstructed anyway.  In the larger implementation, however, perhaps this has a larger purpose.

Hope that Helps!  Feel free to ignore anything that wasn't useful :)

Comment: This workaround works.  Thanks for the keen eye on the other issues, both are just artifacts of my limited example.